# Is there something wrong with the way I am writing this VBA For Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that will copy data over from one worksheet into another, I keep getting an error specifically on the line where I implement my For loop, the error says "Application-defined or object-defined error", any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Global qty As Variant

***********

Sub PartOrder()


qty = Application.InputBox("How many assemblies are needed?")

Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
PartOrderForm.Show



End Sub
```

---

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then


ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "Part Number"
ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = "Part Name"
ActiveSheet.Range("C1") = "Number of Parts Needed"
Range("A2").Activate
For i = 2 To 8
ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1) = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Cells(8 - i, 2)
Next i

Else: End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Aside from the answers you have received, you can also remove the for loop entirely. VBA allows you to copy an array of values from one range to another. You could directly do `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(7).Value = Worksheets("F8X SUSPENSION LINKS REV2").Cells(2, 2).Resize(7).Value` and copy all 7 values in a single line. No loop needed.

Answer (score 0):

When the counter reaches 8, you are referring to 8-i row, which turns out to be 0 resulting in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an off by one error

This part of your code Cells(8 - i, 2), goes to Cell 0. And in excel, it the cell index needs to start with 1